# Application crashes when i try to access phone's external memory

Tags: java, android, directory

I have created a simple application which tries to access a phone's external storage files and display it on an alert box the code goes something like this.

```
btnShowDeviceFolders.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CharSequence items[];

            final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            final File path =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                            (
                                    //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                                    //File.separator +"/"
                            );
            if(!path.exists())
            {
                //path.mkdirs();
             System.out.println("No file found");
            }
            String[] files = path.list();
            if (files.length == 0) {
                //System.out.println("The directory is empty");

            } else {
                for (String aFile : files) {

                    //System.out.println(aFile);
                    list.add(aFile);
                }
            }
            items = files;

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select Project Folder");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),list.get(item),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

But this code works fine on the emulator it lists me the folders that are present, but when i build the `apk` and test it on my mobile it crashes(I'm using android Oreo for testing). The Stacktrace does not give any errors 
[image]
 What can I do to overcome this issue.

Comment: Can you give us the stacktrace ? I do think it's because you forgot about the permission.

Comment: If you mean the permission for reading and writing external storage then I have added those as well `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` @SamiTahri

Comment: Give the stacktrace of the error (when it crashes on your device, not the emulator). Did you accept the permission on the device, as you may not have requested them (check under the Application in your Android Parameters) ?

Comment: On the top left hand side of your logcat the dropdown is set to show data from the emulator. If both devices are running you will need to manually select the mobile.

Comment: Yes It is the permissions issue @SamiTahri . I haven't given any specific permissions to read external storage. Can you please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` run time.
[here is the tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/)

Answer (score 1):

Give permission for external memory in the android_manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You are only giving permission in manifest that is not sufficient you need to give runtime permission .

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //Show Information about why you need the permission
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,false)) {
            //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
            // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    sentToSettings = true;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else {
            //just request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,true);
        editor.commit();


    } else {
        //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
        proceedAfterPermission();
    }
```